# Run bundle exec from crontab

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I need to be able to run `bundle exec ...` from crontab, but it's not working since I made a few changes to my user's login profile that invokes a script on start.

So, I used to have `bash -lc 'BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/location/of/Gemfile bundle exec /location/of/script'`

However, I can't do that anymore since the end of my user's `~/.profile` invokes an whiptail menu dialog (`menu.sh`), thus, any `bash -l` command invokes the `menu.sh`.

I've tried changing the crontab line to `bash -c 'BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/location/of/Gemfile bundle exec /location/of/script'` but that doesn't work either.

Is there another way?  I should note that the ruby script I'm attempting to run does require the use of environment variables that I've placed in `/etc/environment`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works if I get rid of `bash -lc` and reference the full path of `bundle`:

`BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/location/of/Gemfile /root/.rbenv/shims/bundle exec /location/of/script`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Gem called `Whenever`:

[Gem Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

It will make your life much easier with `crontab` and `rake`